# Double forward proxy situation client(A) -> nginx(B) -> squid(C) -> <internet> -> server (D)

Tags: nginx, curl, proxy, squid

My end server URL is app.sample.com/v1/get/health
Now my client will reach to server to get the health.
But Client Machine (A) and the machine(B) on which nginx is running doesn't have the internet (air gapped) but machine (C) on which squid is running is connected to the internet and server (D).

A(client) is able to talk to B(nginx)

B(nginx) is able to talk to C (squid)

C(squid) is able to talk to D(server)

but when I am configuring the nginx on B and squid on C, request is not forwarding from C to server (D).

Nginx config

```
http {
    error_log /etc/nginx/error_log.log warn;

    server {
        server_name localhost;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://<squid-host>:<squid-port>/;
        }

        listen 32708;
    }
}
```

Squid

```
http_port 3128 accel allow-direct
```

Curl request from machine B (this is not working)

```
curl <nginx-ip>:32708/www.google.com
```

Nginx logs

```
20.1.1.2 - - [15/Feb/2022:10:03:10 +0000] "GET /www.google.com HTTP/1.1" 400 3544 "-" "curl/7.58.0"
```

Squid

```
The following error was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL: <a href="www.google.com">www.google.com
<p>Some aspect of the requested URL is incorrect.</p>

<p>Some possible problems are:</p>
<ul>
<li><p>Missing or incorrect access protocol (should be <q>http://</q> or similar)</p></li>
<li><p>Missing hostname</p></li>
<li><p>Illegal double-escape in the URL-Path</p></li>
<li><p>Illegal character in hostname; underscores are not allowed.</p></li>
</ul>
ERR_INVALID_URL

1644919643.574      0 20.1.1.2 TAG_NONE/400 3913 GET www.google.com - HIER_NONE/- text/html
```

When I tried curl using this way from machine B, I am able to get the response. (this is working)

```
http_proxy="http://<squid-host>:<squid-port>" curl -I http://www.google.com
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
P3P: CP="This is not a P3P policy! See g.co/p3phelp for more info."
Date: Tue, 15 Feb 2022 09:57:42 GMT
Server: gws
X-XSS-Protection: 0
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Expires: Tue, 15 Feb 2022 09:57:42 GMT
Cache-Control: private
Set-Cookie: 1P_JAR=2022-02-15-09; expires=Thu, 17-Mar-2022 09:57:42 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; Secure
Set-Cookie: NID=511=j5ZU92fz-JUCQxj__gIdZavA8mOLyiUe_2gp-ZPePQXcV7RgruMLwf36C3Imdt5oTm__xQdGkcNgHBliaEhB7eeXR6gtjaQidHWcebo3w0YXhgUlmZ2YFC3dx5vb4YbpZIr8gmCUcWdPlz8tmSA2c7FYYnZNbegkb9QWe5ybSUU; expires=Wed, 17-Aug-2022 09:57:42 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; HttpOnly
X-Cache: MISS from anilhost
X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from sample:3128
Via: 1.1 sample (squid/3.5.27)
Connection: keep-alive
```

Squid

```
1644919591.994     50 20.1.1.2 TCP_MISS/200 804 HEAD http://www.google.com/ - HIER_DIRECT/216.58.195.68 text/html
```